# Time taking for training data. LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

My data set contains 10 days' data of 1000 users. I am training and testing the data for each individual user for better prediction accuracy. The issue is for the first user training 100 epochs takes `5 secs` and for the 100th user, 100 epochs takes more than `five minutes`. The training time is increasing for each user. How to reduce the training time> As the location points are categorical, One hot encoding is implemented for encoding the location points.

```
list = list_users[:100]
with open("accuracy_Lstm.csv","w") as f:
    f.write('user,LSTM \n')
    for user in list:
        user_data = newdataframe[newdataframe.user==user]
        encoded=encoding(user_data)
        X_train = []
        y_train = []
        for i in range(1, len(encoded)-96):
            X_train.append(encoded[i-1])
            y_train.append(encoded[i])
        X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
        X_test = encoded[-192:-96,:]
        X_true = encoded[-96:,:]
        X_trainL=X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],1,X_train.shape[1])
        time_steps = 1
    #Lstm
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(X_train.shape[1], input_shape=(time_steps,X_train.shape[1]), activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1]))
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
        model.fit(X_trainL, y_train, batch_size=96, epochs=100, verbose =1)
        model.summary()

        X_testL=X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],1,X_test.shape[1])

        pedL =one_hot_decode(model.predict(X_testL))
        true=one_hot_decode(X_true)
        try:
            accuracy = ((sum(x == y for x, y in zip(pedL, true)))/(len(pedL)))*100
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            accuracy = 0
        f.write(' %d,  %f \n'%(user, accuracy))
```

How to reduce the training time for users?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are recreating a new model at each iteration in the for loop. This is quite memory intensive for each model, and should be avoided. This is why the first model train quite fast, and then slower for each new model. Even `del model` at each iteration would not help since the memory leak is in tensorflow. You could potentially clear session in the beginning of the for loop, but this in itself is quite slow.

I suggest you create the model outside the loop, and then just re-initiate the weights of the model at each iteration (as the model architecture does not change between iteration)

---

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the comment, here is an example code of how this idea can be implemented. As the question is not a working code in itself, I have not tested and verified that the following code is working without a memory leak, but from my previous experience I think it should.

```py
list = list_users[:100]

def get_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(X_train.shape[1], input_shape=(time_steps,X_train.shape[1]), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1]))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    model.summary()
    return(model, model.get_weights())

with open("accuracy_Lstm.csv","w") as f:
    f.write('user,LSTM \n')
    model, initial_weights = get_model()
    for user in list:
        user_data = newdataframe[newdataframe.user==user]
        encoded=encoding(user_data)
        X_train = []
        y_train = []
        for i in range(1, len(encoded)-96):
            X_train.append(encoded[i-1])
            y_train.append(encoded[i])
        X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
        X_test = encoded[-192:-96,:]
        X_true = encoded[-96:,:]
        X_trainL=X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],1,X_train.shape[1])
        time_steps = 1
    #Lstm
        model.set_weights(initial_weights)
        model.fit(X_trainL, y_train, batch_size=96, epochs=100, verbose =1)

        X_testL=X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],1,X_test.shape[1])

        pedL =one_hot_decode(model.predict(X_testL))
        true=one_hot_decode(X_true)
        try:
            accuracy = ((sum(x == y for x, y in zip(pedL, true)))/(len(pedL)))*100
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            accuracy = 0
        f.write(' %d,  %f \n'%(user, accuracy))
```

---

**EDIT2:**

Since the shape of the model is changing for each user, you will need to create the model at each iteration. therefor the above solution will not work.
You can clear the tensorflow memory by `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()`, but it is quite slow (that is why i tried to avoid it in the solution above). The following solution will probably be slower than 5 seconds for each user (due to the added clear time), but should be constant for each used independent on the number of users you have.

```
list = list_users[:100]

def get_model(input_size):
    # clear the memory of tensorflow before creating a new model
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    # creare new model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(input_size, input_shape=(time_steps,input_size), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(input_size))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    model.summary()
    return(model)

with open("accuracy_Lstm.csv","w") as f:
    f.write('user,LSTM \n')
    for user in list:
        # clear the memory of tensorflow at each new model
        tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

        user_data = newdataframe[newdataframe.user==user]
        encoded=encoding(user_data)
        X_train = []
        y_train = []
        for i in range(1, len(encoded)-96):
            X_train.append(encoded[i-1])
            y_train.append(encoded[i])
        X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
        X_test = encoded[-192:-96,:]
        X_true = encoded[-96:,:]
        X_trainL=X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],1,X_train.shape[1])
        time_steps = 1
    #Lstm
        model = get_model(X_train.shape[1])
        model.fit(X_trainL, y_train, batch_size=96, epochs=100, verbose =1)

        X_testL=X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],1,X_test.shape[1])

        pedL =one_hot_decode(model.predict(X_testL))
        true=one_hot_decode(X_true)
        try:
            accuracy = ((sum(x == y for x, y in zip(pedL, true)))/(len(pedL)))*100
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            accuracy = 0
        f.write(' %d,  %f \n'%(user, accuracy))
```

Comment: I am new to machine learning. Can you help me with the change in code? I would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Krush23 Hopefully the above code will help you understand the idea of re-initiating the weights, such that you can tailor the solution to your case.

Comment: Error occured `<ipython-input-6-5316296259bb> in get_model()
      3 def get_model():
      4     model = Sequential()
----> 5     model.add(LSTM(X_train.shape[1], input_shape=(1,X_train.shape[1]), activation='relu'))
      6     model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1]))
      7     model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

` Error is   `NameError: name 'X_train' is not defined`

Comment: Obs, I, forgot to fix that!
Is X_train.shape[1] the same for each user or does it changing between them? And if it is static, what is the numeric value of X_train.shape[1]?

Comment: It changes for each user while encoding.

Comment: Can we use `keras.backend.clear_session()` to clear the previous model.

Comment: Yes, check edit2. That should work to clear the tensorflow memory, but its unfortunately quite slow. So training will probably be slower until you get to a high number of users.
at least `clear_session()` will give constant run time, while the old code is increasing in time for each iteration.